# How can I get Leaflet Icons from a specific host?

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to get dynamically generated icons from a specific host.

I try to define a new icon class, and change `iconUrl` and `iconRetinaUrl` like so:

```
var opts = L.Icon.Default.prototype.options;

opts.iconUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/marker?c=blue';
opts.iconRetinaUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/marker?c=blue';

var houseIcon = L.Icon.Default.extend({ options: opts });
```

and later use the icon.

```
var theIcon = new houseIcon();
var marker = L.marker([loc.lat, loc.lon], { 'icon': theIcon }).addTo(map);
```

All I get is missing images, and see that the browser is trying to get the icons from

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.5.1/images/http://localhost:3001/marker?c=blue
```

Obviously with a 404 answer.

I cannot see something like a `baseUrl` option in the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#icon-option) that for iconUrl says "The URL to the icon image (absolute or relative to your script path)."

How can I get icons from a different location than the script? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Extend `L.Icon` rather than `L.Icon.Default`.Example at https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/. The `iconUrl` setting is a URL that can be fully-qualified or relative to the script.

Comment: @peeebeee - that works, thanks! I found out I also have to override the shadowUrl option with a full URL